# what is wrong with the HashMap?

Tags: java, user-interface, hashmap

My Code:

It's a GUI program

I draw some rectangle, and put them in the HashMap shapes(use addShape());
The `currShape` point to the shape that the mouse hold.
When the mouse press(mousePressed()) I want to chang the item , but I can't find it though the hashCode() and equal() are the same.

```
HashMap<Shape, ShapeInfo> shapes;
private Shape currShape = null;

public void addShape(Point point)
{
    switch (actState)
    {
    case DRAWREC:
        currShape = new Rectangle(point);
        break;

    case DRAWCIR:
        currShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(point.getX(), point.getY(), 10.0, 10.0);
        break;

    case DRAWLIN:
        currShape = new Line2D.Double(point.getX(), point.getY(), point.getX(), point.getY());
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    shapes.put(currShape, new ShapeInfo(false, color));
    repaint();
}


public Shape findShape(Point point)
{
    int curx = point.x, cury = point.y;

    for (Shape shape : shapes.keySet())
    {
        if (shape instanceof Rectangle)
        {
            Rectangle rec = (Rectangle)shape;
            if (!drawCompleted(rec) && (rec.contains(point) ||
                rec.contains(curx, cury - ShapeInfo.SIZE) || rec.contains(curx, cury + ShapeInfo.SIZE) ||
                rec.contains(curx - ShapeInfo.SIZE, cury) || rec.contains(curx + ShapeInfo.SIZE, cury)))
                return shape;
        }
    }
    return null;
}



public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
{
        Shape shape = findShape(event.getPoint());
    System.out.println(shape);
    if (currShape != null && currShape != shape)
        setComplted();

    currShape = shape;
    if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && 
        currShape == null || drawCompleted(currShape))
        addShape(event.getPoint());

    posState = getPos(event.getPoint());
}


public void setComplted()
{
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("Completed");
        System.out.println(shapes.size());
        for (Shape shape : shapes.keySet())
        {
            if (shape.equals(currShape))
                System.out.println("equal : " + shape + ":" + shape.hashCode());
            else
                System.out.println(shape + ":" + shape.hashCode());
        }


        System.out.println("Current" + ":" + currShape + ":" + currShape.hashCode());

        System.out.println(shapes.containsKey(currShape) + "\n");


    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result is

```
equal
java.awt.Rectangle[x=199,y=37,width=176,height=194]:776675328
java.awt.Rectangle[x=199,y=37,width=176,height=194]:776675328
false
```

The `hashCode()` are the same and `equals()` return true, but why `containKey` return false?
Why it can not find the `currShape` in shapes?

Comment: Do you use standard HashMap and Shape classes implementations? The code works for me

Comment: Can you provide the code where `shapes` is instanciated. Also, what is the class used `currShape` and put in `shapes`??

Comment: did you override `equal` in shape?

Comment: There is no problem here too, can you post your full code

Comment: If you do not override `equals` method then reference are compared only.

Comment: @Areo I have not override the `equal`, but in `shapes`, there is a shape euqals to the `currShape`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Rectangle` is a mutable class and instances of mutable classes are not good hash keys. Once you have added them, you *must not* modify them. If you modify them after the addition their hash code changes and the lookup might fail. You will still encounter the object when iterating but all operations relying on the hash code (and its immutability) will fail.

Note that if you don’t need a lookup regarding equal instances in the sense of the `equals` method but want to look up the instances you can use a [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html). This will ignore the state of the shapes and find the instances even if mutated but, e.g. creating an equivalent `Rectangle` to find a match, won’t work than. You can’t have both.

Comment: but before the `System.out.println(shapes.containsKey(currShape) + "\n"); ` the currShape's hashCode are the same with one in shapes, but when it judge, it return false?

Comment: The problem is that the hashCode differs from the hashCode the Shape had *when adding* it to the hash map. You don’t see which hashCode the `Map` has remembered.